# I removed eclipse from my system, but the dash board still shows the icon

Tags: icons, eclipse

The eclipse package files are not even found in the synaptic.
I did not even find any positive search results of "eclipse" even in the hidden folders .
How could I remove the junk icon of eclipse?
But there are some results of eclipse in the root folder of ubuntu such as in usr/share/app-install/desktop etc. but I cannot delete it from the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse

rm -r ~/.eclipse/
```